# What software and hardware would be needed to make an iPad work like a TV accepting data from the lightning port?

Tags: ios, ipad, usb, hdmi

I am trying to have my iPad (3rd gen) read television / video type HDMI input.

I have an HDMI to USB-C conversion cable and the iPad is recognizing the accessory (not sure how you know this, please edit).

I want to parse this data, and then display it on screen as video-in. Similar to how the Duet Display are doing it (an explanation of a similar setup is here - http://thecodewash.blogspot.com/2017/05/communicating-with-your-ios-app-over.html)

I'm not against the whole Peertalk approach if need be, but it seems like it would require an extra device (likely a raspberry Pi) as an intermediary somewhere in the process.

I am wondering - are there any software packages that would allow me to just to read the data stream for a USB connection into an iPad?

Comment: I’ve read this a couple times and can’t understand what you’re looking for. All sorts of iOS apps can talk via the USB port so this is clearly - yes this is possible. I’m not sure how HDMI enters or Duet app enters. Are you looking for an app to send data or manage a pi? What’s the practical problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: I am trying to use my iPad as a television, essentially. I want to send HDMI data (with an HDMI to USB C converter) to my iPad and then display it, probably in a custom app as no apps to do this seem to exist

Comment: OK - I’ve edited this now that I get what you seek.  1. API calls are off topic here - perhaps ask what API can process video in on Stack Overflow. 2. Software recommendations are on topic here, so let’s see if there are any you could adopt/buy/compile.